# Sinon function stubbing: How to call "own" function inside module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I am writing some unit tests for node.js code and I use Sinon to stub function calls via

```
var myFunction = sinon.stub(nodeModule, 'myFunction');
myFunction.returns('mock answer');
```

The `nodeModule` would look like this

```
module.exports = {
  myFunction: myFunction,
  anotherF: anotherF
}

function myFunction() {

}

function anotherF() {
  myFunction();
}
```

Mocking works obviously for use cases like `nodeModule.myFunction()`, but I am wondering how can I mock the myFunction() call inside anotherF() when called with `nodeModule.anotherF()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can refactor your module a little. Like this.

```
var service = {
   myFunction: myFunction,
   anotherFunction: anotherFunction
}

module.exports = service;

function myFunction(){};

function anotherFunction() {
   service.myFunction(); //calls whatever there is right now
}
```

Comment: Fair enough :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it for reasons of good practice or why doesn't Sinon provide stubbing without an object reference?

Comment: @lukas_o Not sure I understand your question correctly. You could create a stub just like this `const myStub = sinon.stub()` the problem is to tell the rest of your code to use you stub instead of original function.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks, sometimes you have functions where you can't inject the reference, so you have to wrap the myFunction, as you did in service. I miss something like `var myFunction = sinon.stub('myFunction');` without passing the object.

Comment: @lukas_o But the problem is `myFunction` is your local variable referencing a stub while `myFuncton` inside another module reference totally different function. And you can't change references even if you have access to it (because references are passed by value). To do this you need to "instrument" your loaded module somehow. Either manually as in the code above or say using `rewire` module.