# How can I stub internally referenced functions with sinonjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I have a **myModule** Node.js module containing:

```
function b() {
  console.log('original b');
}

function a() {
  b();
}

exports.a = a
exports.b = b;
```

And the following test suite using mocha + sinon.js:

```
const myModule = require('./myModule.js');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('not working stub', () => {
  it('should call the stub', () => {
    let stub = sinon.stub(myModule, 'b', () => { console.log('stubbed b')});
    myModule.a();
    expect(stub).to.have.been.called;
  })
});
```

I am expecting the stub to be called, but the original b get called instead, why ?

Comment: From what I understand, `function b` is encapsulated within `function a` by the time it's imported, and hence when you stub `function b`, it's not referencing the same object. I had a similar issue and the way I got around it was to stub by reference. e.g. `function a() {exports.b()}`;

Comment: Ok I see. If I rephrase you well, when I am stubbing exports.b , I am changing the value referenced by exports.b, but this does not change the function b which is called in function a.

Comment: I am not sure to be honest as I haven't dug that deep, but it's possible. You can test it by changing the first file to `export default function b () {...}` and exporting `function a` into exports object.
Then you import function b by itself, and not as part of an object and see if that affects the stubbing. e.g. `import b from './myModule'` and `import {a} from './myModule'`

Comment: I think you may be correct. I wrote this block a month ago to help myself understand what's happening.
It seems to match what you are saying 
https://github.com/charzy/stub-reference-example/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sinon function stubbing: How to call "own" function inside module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162659/sinon-function-stubbing-how-to-call-own-function-inside-module)

Comment: If you want your stub to be used maybe you need to pass it as a param and declare it in the test as an spy

Answer (score -1):

var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);

This has been removed from v3.0.0. Instead you should use
stub(object, 'method').callsFake(fn).
Or you could use .yields(fn)

https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/

Comment: I don't believe this answers the user's question.